# How do I set the "readonly" attribute on the whole form of the model

Tags: odoo

I'm having trouble getting read-only an entire form in model sale_order.
In order for both my form to readonly, it needs to reach the domain I specified,
It includes the fact that when I click on the button I added new and include a state in two states either in 'a' or in 'b' (my domain is functioning properly)
I tried the ways I found online but they did not meet enough.

read-only does not work for both the form / or tree. then I have the idea of hiding the Edit button:
followed by

```
<xpath expr="// form" position = "attributes" />
<attribute name="edit">false</attribute>
```

It hides the button, but I can't add attrs or attributes to *"edit"*.

In the two ways read-only form and hide the edit button, I failed.

Comment: what you mean by readonly, you mean remove edit button, and you want to remove it based on a field like `state` for example, try to explain better

Comment: hi, due to my sentence.
1, I have a button
def action_kiem_soat_xac_nhan (self):
         self.write ({'x_trangthaiduyet': 'da_xac_nhan'})
I want after the button is clicked, SO will readonly. (after clicking this button, the state will not change [state = 'da_gui_bcdh)
and the condition I have set is
['|', ('x_trangthaiduyet', 'in', ['da_xac_nhan']), ('state', 'in', ['da_gui_bcdh', 'done'])].
I don't see any solution to do this (field_view_get function needs to reload the page, I don't want that.)

Comment: 2. I thought the second solution was to hide the edit button when I clicked the "action_kiem_soat_xac_nhan" button, as I said above.
<xpath expr = "// form" position = "attributes" />
<attribute name = "edit"> false </attribute>
The problem is that it cannot receive the domain as the condition above

Answer (score 0):

You can add record rule for that model, where you can apply your domain so that user can not edit that model.

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried the rule, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I succeeded in interfering with js